# Authentic alternatives for "because"

Tags: phrase-request

Someone told me that native speakers seldom begin a sentence with "because" in conversation. But I am wondering what are the possible authentic alternatives for "because"? Examples are invited and more than welcome!

Comment: I would question the value (and indeed, *truth*) of the assertion that *native speakers seldom begin a sentence with "because"*. But to the extent that it *might* be true, it won't be to do with the actual word "because*. It'll be because the natural sequence is *"I will do this **because** of that"* (i.e. - the two preferred ways of expressing such causal relationships are ***X** because/since/as/due to **Y*** and ***Y** so/hence/thus/therefore **X***). It's just unnecessarily complex in conversation to announce the relationship "direction" before specifying *either* cause or effect.

Comment: I think this is more a word order phenomenon due to spoken sentences being largely unplanned, so *because* tends to come later in speech.  You don't need to avoid *because*, I don't think.

Comment: **As** it is raining today, I'm not going out!

Comment: Indeed, I may not have formulated my question to a sufficient extent. I know the synonyms, quasi or precise, for "because". The alternative expressions I seek are like, for instance, to begin a sentence with "The thing is ..." or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most casual replacements I can think of is *since*:

> Since I ate an hour ago, I'm not hungry right now.

There are a lot more formal replacements, but none that you would hear in conversation very frequently.

Comment: Or, we could do without both *because* and *since*: "I ate an hour ago, **so** I'm not hungry right now.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes, I choose one ordering over another, even in casual situations, depending on which part I want the listener to hear first.

Comment: We could do without any conjunctions at all: "I ate an hour ago. I'm not hungry right now." Any listener could detect the causation.

Comment: @ ಠ_ಠ: Exactly the point of my comment to the question. How often do you want the first thing the listener hears to be the "causative conjunction", given that it doesn't "mean" anything until you've also supplied the relevant *cause* and/or *effect*. In your example, almost certainly you want him to hear the most important bit *(I'm not hungry)* - so you say that first, then tack on the (effectively, optional) justification afterwards.

Comment: *since* denotes *time* in most of the contexts (here too!). If you replace *because* with **as**, I think the message is conveyed in almost all instances. Nevertheless, not all **as's** can be replaced by *because* when the sentence begins with it! *As you like!* :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of these examples sound like a child responding to a question the child finds annoying.  (Which might explain why many adults try to avoid sounding like this.)

"Why didn't you use another word there?"

- "'Cause I like that one."

"Why did you do that?"

- "Because."
- "Just because."
- "So I wouldn't be late."
- "To get it done."
- "In order to finish on time."
- "Because she was hitting me!"
- "To stop the pain."

"What was that for?"

- "He hit me, so I hit him back!"
- "To get even."
- "For all those times he cheated!"

"Why don't you go outside and play?"

- "Because it's hot out!"
- "Because I don't wanna!"
- "I don't want to."
- "But we like it in here."
- "It's raining, and I left my raincoat at home."
- "Why should we?"

(" 'Cause" rhymes with "buzz", not "paws".)